# Wrapping existing async method into TPL-compatiable method

Tags: .net, asynchronous, task-parallel-library, async-ctp

How to wrap existing async method that accepts callback function as parameter into Task Parallel Library-compatible method?

```
// Existing method
void DoAsync(Action<string> callback) {
    ...
}

// The desired method should have similar prototype
Task<string> DoAsync() {
    // Internally this method should call existing
    // version of DoAsync method (see above)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that your existing `DoAsync` method will run asynchronously.

In that case, you can wrap it like this:

```
Task<string> DoAsyncTask()
{
  var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
  DoAsync(result => tcs.TrySetResult(result));
  return tcs.Task;
}
```

I don't see how your existing `DoAsync` method reports asynchronous errors. You can use `TaskCompletionSource<T>.TrySetException` to report an asynchronous error if necessary.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what need and looks pretty nice!